# Customizing element name n wsdl

Tags: wsdl

I have a requirement, in my SOAP I have to use fields which have `-` (hyphen) in their names, which cannot be used in Java objects as field names.

For example

```
<RegisterUser> 
   <user-pin></user-pin> 
   <user-id></user-id> 
</RegisterUser>
```

And in Java I have a class `RegisterUser` and it has fields `userPin`, `userId` (I cannot name it `user-pin`, `user-id`).

Is there any way we can use webparam annotation to map it ?

I tried `XmlElement` annotation also but its not generating the corresponding mapping in wsdl instead its generating with the java element name itself.

I am using the below ant script to generate wsdl from my java.

```
     <target name="build-wsdl">
   <!--Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
   <jwsc srcdir="${src}" destdir="${ear-dir}" debug="${debug}" debuglevel="${debuglevel}">
      <jws file="com/user/service/LoginService.java"/>
   <classpath>
     <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
       <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
   </classpath>
   </jwsc>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jax-ws implementation of your webservice in java. you can use @WebParam annotation like below.

```
public interface RegisterUser{
@WebMethod String getRegisterUser( @WebParam (name="user-id") String userID, @WebParam(name="user-pin" String userPin);}
```

Now your generated wsdl element for this method would be,

```
<message name="getRegisterUser">
<part name="user-id" type="xsd:string"></part>
<part name="user-pin" type="xsd:string"></part>
</message>
```

Is this what are you looking for?